# Short story about humans -> machines -> disembodied spirits

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I've been scouring the internet trying to find a science fiction piece I remember reading when I was in elementary school.

It was very short and about how humans will evolve into machines leaving our flesh/physical bodies behind. Then, the machines would eventually wear/rust and the intelligence/consciousness would then leave as a spirit/ghost. The piece was predicting that this would be how humans progress.

I thought it was a popular poem/short story but I can't find it anywhere. I also thought it was authored by Asimov but I couldn't find anything.

I just graduated from college if that gives some perspective. I would say it was between 3rd and 7th grade for me--so it was between 2004-2009 that I had read this piece in school.

Comment: You say when you was in school when was that?

Comment: I just graduated from college if that gives some perspective. I would say it was between 3rd and 7th grade for me--so between 2004-2009.

Comment: You can [edit] that into the question!

Comment: We had just finished Asimov's "Hallucination" and subsequently we read this very short piece that I cannot remember the name or author

Comment: This was a common theme in Arthur Clarke's writing. Do you remember anything about the plot?

Comment: Are you sure this was a standalone work and not an extract from *2001: A Space Odyssey*?

Comment: There wasn't really a plot, and definitely no characters. It was more of a general outlook/prediction of human progression. It couldn't have been a couple of pages long (perhaps even a single page (hence, why I said it could be considered a poem perhaps)).

Comment: 'The robot body, like the flesh-and-blood one, would be no more than a steppingstone to something which, long ago, men bad called "spirit."' from 2001. Thank you so much @OrganicMarble and jwodder you are literally the best! I've been looking for this for years and you found it in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @OrganicMarble just curious, do you know any other short stories or books from Clarke, specifically, that cover this theme?

Comment: I think it comes up in "City and the Stars" and some of the short works.  People transferring their minds into spaceships and then just energy beings is just associated with Clarke to me.

Comment: @Jason sounds like you should write an answer to your own question - which is perfectly OK in stack exchange.

Comment: @OrganicMarble ok got it, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The piece is an extract from Arthur C. Clarke's *2001: A Space Odyssey*. It was not a standalone piece of literature.

The passage I was trying to remember is as follows:

"There were other thinkers, Bowman also found, who held even more exotic views. They did not
believe that really advanced beings would possess organic bodies at all. Sooner or later, as their
scientific knowledge progressed, they would get rid of the fragile, disease-and-accident-prone
homes that Nature had given them, and which doomed them to inevitable death. They would replace
their natural bodies as they wore out - or perhaps even before that - by constructions of metal
and plastic, and would thus achieve immortality. The brain might linger for a little while as the
last remnant of the organic body, directing its mechanical limbs and observing the universe
through its electronic senses - senses far finer and subtler than those that blind evolution could
ever develop.
 Even on Earth, the first steps in this direction had been taken. There were millions of men,
doomed in earlier ages, who now lived active and happy lives thanks to artificial limbs, kidneys,
lungs, and hearts. To this process there could be only one conclusion - however far off it might
be.
 And eventually even the brain might go. As the seat of consciousness, It was not essential;
the development of electronic intelligence had proved that. The conflict between mind and machine
might be resolved at last in the eternal truce of complete symbiosis.
 But was even this the end? A few mystically inclined biologists went still further. They
speculated, taking their cues from the beliefs of many religions, that mind would eventually free
itself from matter. The robot body, like the flesh-and-blood one, would be no more than a steppingstone to something which, long ago, men bad called "spirit."
 And if there was anything beyond that, its name could only be God."

Thank you to @OrganicMarble and @jwodder for helping me find the source.